# Nodejs: session is undefined after generating

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I have a problem in using express 4 and express-session in my node/html project.

1. The `login.html` makes an ajax call to the node program.
2. If it succeeds, node generates a session remembering the user name in the attribute `req.session.username` and return a file name `csmain.html` to `login.html`. `login.html` then redirects the browser to `csmain.html`.
3. The `csmain.html` then makes an ajax call in its `load()` immediately, but the problem is at this time the session seems to not be ready. The `req.session.user` is undefined in node. That means the session has not been used by the browser in the ajax call in `load()`.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

code in node's login part to generate a session

```
request.session.regenerate(function(err) {
});
if (request.session.views ) {
  // empty
} else {
  request.session.views = 1;
  request.session.username = username;
}
```

html redirect --javascript part in the login html. The 1st character in the `xmlHttp.responseText` is the status of login, the remaining text is the http link

```
if (status === BDX_ERR_SQL_WRONG_PASSWORD) {
    document.getElementById("feedbackMsg").innerHTML = 'login error';
}else if (status === '0') {
    window.location = '../' + xmlHttp.responseText.substring(1, len);
}
```

Comment: What kind of session store are you using?  In some cases, `regenereate()` may be asynchronous, which would mean it is not done until it's callback is called so you'd have to put the code that uses the new session inside the regenerate callback.

Comment: @jfiend00 I am using redis as backstore for session. What is the callback of regenerate? I can not find at express-session website. Can u give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a database as a session store, then it is likely that the `regenerate()` call is asynchronous.  That means that `regenerate()` is not done until the callback is called so you would need to do it this way:

```
request.session.regenerate(function(err) {
    // should do error checking here

    if (request.session.views ) {
        // empty
    } else {
        request.session.views = 1;
        request.session.username = username;
    }

    // continue with the rest of your code flow here inside the callback

});
```

Express session doc here: https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionregenerate

Comment: thanks a lot, it works now after I put all the remaining code into regenerate(){...} including the response.writ('csmain.html')... I had tried before putting just the session attributes assignment line into it, and it had not worked.